Are there any standards that specify line weights for Function Block Diagrams?
Are there any standards out there that specify what line weights should be used when creating a Function Block Diagram or other similar block diagrams used in software, systems, or controls engineering?
For example, I see some texts that show a functions rectangle symbol to be a heavier line weight than the arrows for example. Even the arrow line weights and styles I would like to know.

there are corporate standards
